# How to close tab in tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux

Is there a shortcut key to close a tab?
I'm asking for something like creating a tab `CTRL b + c`
What shortcut should I use if I would like to close the `1:cmatrix*` tab?
[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://www.dayid.org/os/notes/tm.html

Specifically this part:

```
kill the current pane: ^b x OR (logout/^D)  
close other panes except the current one: ^b !  

The formatting here is simple enough to understand (I would hope). 
^ means ctrl+, so ^x is ctrl+x. M- means meta (generally left-alt or escape)+,
so M-x is left-alt+x
```

Comment: Thank you Webbies. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: "" kill the current pane: ^b x OR (logout/^D) "" = Ctrl+b x

Comment: Additionally, you can also do ```^d``` or just type ```exit``` after you have quit (```^c```) the current running program in the terminal.

Answer (score 11):

```sh
prefix+x: kill the current pane
prefix+&: kill the current window
```

Note the difference between pane and window. OP actually wants to kill a window. So prefix+& will be better suited especially when a window has multiple pane splits.

Answer (score 0):

It is not precisely the question but I reached this pane needing it.
If you want to close a pane from another you can try listing the panes and killing it from id.

```
tmux list-panes
```

Should return something like:

```
0: [209x67] [history 284/2000, 167338 bytes] %2 (active)
1: [209x19] [history 722/2000, 256904 bytes] %1
```

Simply use this to kill the one you want:

```
tmux kill-pane -t #PANENUMBER
```